# Windows can not access specific file, path, or file, you may not have the appropriate permission to access them

Tags: .net-framework

the OS of my machine is XPSP3, then I ghost it to Win2008 server, but when I run a exe or access some folder on partion D, it pops up "Windows can not access specific file, path, or file, you may not have the appropriate permission to access them“，the user I log in is the administrator, so that puzzles me a lot, does anyone can help me ?

Comment: Not a programming-related question. Try asking on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

You have a computer with a partition, C, that contains a Windows 2008 Server installation and a partition, D, that contains a Windows XP SP3 installation and you are trying to access a file in the XP file system from 2008. Is that correct?

I'd say that being an administrator does not automatically give you unrestricted access to everything in the file system. If you are using NTFS, and I presume you are, then file access is controlled by security descriptors. It is likely that the security descriptors do not contain information about the administrator account that you are trying to use.

If you check the security settings on the files that you are trying to access, who is the owner and what permissions have been assigned to individual users?